# Re-paste matrix to other matrix

Tags: excel, vba

I am a complete newbie with VBA, but I have few thousand lines of data in the file and I presume that a macro is the only possible solution to my problem.

Here is an illustration of my problem:

[image]

I would like to:

1. Copy all particulars cells line by line from specific range `A2:E5` to one new column (*can be in another worksheet*)
2. Copy data from columns next to the specified in point 1 range (columns `F` and `G`) to the appropriate rows received after point 1 is performed

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Also what would happen if `X8` was in Cell C3 as well? i.e in two places `C3` and `A4` or this situation will not arise?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Such situation will not arise, all cells within range A2 : E2 are unique. It would be hard to show to show what I have done so far, cause I am new with VBA, firstly I tried all excel formulas (pivots, vlookups etc.), but I have not manage to do it. Maybe if you can't tell how to solve the issue, just put me on the right track with what do i have to look for or with what I have to get acquainted.

Comment: Great. Can you show us some efforts by giving it a try by yourself. And if you are still stuck then post the code that you tried? We will then take it from there?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, please see the previous post edited.

Comment: Ok Here is the logic. `1` Save all the items from range "A2:E5" in an array `2` Add a new sheet `3` Output that array in Cell A1 of the new sheet `4` Find lastrow in Col A of the new sheet `5` Loop through the cells in Col A of new sheet and use [.FIND](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) to check for the occurrence. `6` If found then get the value from Col F and G into new sheet Col B and C. As simple as that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually solve this without VBA, using plain Excel formulas in a smart way:

1. Create a table with 6 columns, a header row and 10 rows (adjust the number of rows according to your data!). for the example, let's assume that you place the table in `J1:O11`.
2. Now add the following formula to each column in row 2 and copy it down to row 11:

   1. Column J ("Source row"): `=IF(ISTEXT(J1),1,IF(K1=L1,J1+1,J1))` - this will determine the source row for each record
   2. Column K ("Column count"): `=IF(J2<>J1,COUNTA(OFFSET($A$1,J2,0,1,5)),K1)` - this counts how many labels (X1, X2, etc.) are in the source row
   3. Column L ("Source column"): `=IF(J2<>J1,1,L1+1)` - this determines the column for the current record
   4. Column M ("Label"): `=INDEX($A$2:$E$5,J2,L2)` - this retrieves the label (X1, X2, etc.)
   5. Column N ("Value1"): `=INDEX($F$2:$F$5,J2)` - this retrieves the first value (AA, CC)
   6. Column O ("Value2"): `=INDEX($G$2:$G$5,J2)` - this retrieves the second value (BB, DD)

Done!

Here's a sample screenshot:
[image]

And here you can download the [sample workbook](https://mega.co.nz/#!XJZxyDBC!O0B2KDpWCPyaOdxWPPYaX21aWT1oz9x83ro-bDF9XG4).

Comment: Your formula solution works perfect! @Siddhart I will follow your remarks and try to solve it with VBA either. Thank you both